# Print odd numbers in Python using continue

Tags: python

I want to print odd numbers within a range using Python with the code below, but I don't understand what is wrong with it and it only prints 1 and stops.

```py
a=1
while a<11:
    if a%2==0:
        continue
    print(a)
    a+=1
```

Comment: Follow what your code does step by step: https://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't increment `a` when it's not odd in the `if` clause.

```python
a=1
while a<11:
    if a%2==0:
        a+=1
        continue
    print(a)
    a+=1
```

You must increment `a` also when it's even, else it will be stuck in an infinite loop at `a=2`.

A better variation would be to avoid `continue` and do as follows:

```python
a=1
while a<11:
    if a%2!=0:
        print(a)
    a+=1
```

Comment: Using continue as a whole is a bad practice IMO and should be avoided, which here it can be easily avoided.

Comment: Agreed. I was explaining to them the problem in their code. But I have taken your suggestion to improve my answer.

Comment: Providing both options is 100% best here. Good answer.

Comment: While in this case `continue` is not needed, saying using `continue` is a bad practice is not true at all. There is nothing wrong with using `continue`.

Comment: @leoOrion Agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 1
while x < 15:
    if x % 2 != 0:
        print(x)
    x = x + 1
```

This is how you do it. Main issue with your code is that continue skips everything, including the increment. Meaning your code causes an infinite loop. Continue skips all other lines in that iteration of a loop and goes to a new one, meaning a never increments meaning a is always less than 11.

Answer (score 1):

Her you go mate:

```
a=1
while a<11:
    if a%2!=0:
        print(a)
    a+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a+=1 before you continue, just know that you can write something more simple then that, and more pretty ;)

```
a=1
while a<11:
    if a%2==0:
        a+=1   ///add this
        continue
    print(a)
    a+=1
```